# use python to dynamically create html grid for row and col

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a row and col grid using python. The basic's is that for the first element in the userName list I should be creating a `<div class="row">`then ideally every forth iteration of the loop I should be closing that row with another div.

The part that is kind of tricking me is if there are say less that 4 elements in the list than I will still need to close the row with another div properly if I am only having say 3 elements in the list or 2 elements in the list.

Hopefully I explained that well enough, please ask question and I will explain what I mean again.

```
    # userName = ['Name1', 'Name2']
    userName = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6', 'Name7', 'Name8']
    # userName = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']

    html_card = ''
    for count, element in enumerate(userName, 1): # Start counting from 1

        # ADDING HTML ROW
        if count % 4 == 0 or count == 1:
            html_card += '<div class="row">'

        # ADDING HTML CARD COL
        html_card += '''\n<div class="col">
                        <div class="card card-block">
                          <div class="card mb-4 border-primary">
                                <div class="card-header bg-primary">{element}</div>
                                <div class="card-body text-primary">
                                  <h4 style="color:#0069d9" class="card-title">{element} Performance Runs</h4>
                                  <p style="color:#0069d9" class="card-text"></p>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()">Available Runs</button>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>\n'''.format(element=element)

        # ADDING HTML ROW DIV
        if count % 4 == 0 or element == userName[-1]:
            html_card += '</div>\n'

        print(html_card)
```

Comment: Would you please provide the related CSS code?

Comment: sure let me attach that. I am not sure there is any since I am using bootstrap here, but let me double check.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle the css is a little off but im not that worried about that as in my setup css is proper. I more worried about my logic from the python side on properly creating the grid system. Also this grid is just a idea of what I am trying to accomplish. https://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/svfjqg0y/3/

Comment: sorry, I made an assumption `<div class= >`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to print the elements of userName in rows of 4. If the last row isn't full, just end the row anyway, like this:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 |
```

For an easier demonstration in the following code, I shortened the HTML in the middle, but it should work anyway. Here we can let Python do the work of keeping track of the positions by using array slices (that is, if `x = [1,2,3,4]`, then `x[0:2]` is `[1,2]`, because `x[a,b]` means the sublist of `x` starting at index `a` and continuing for `b` elements).

So we can loop over the set of rows we want, and slice out the column values, like this:

```
userName = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6', 'Name7']

row_length = 4
html_card = ''
for i in range(0, len(userName), row_length):
    html_card += '<div class="row">'
    for element in userName[i:i+row_length]:
        html_card += '\n<div class="col">{element </div>\n'.format(element=element)
    html_card += '</div>\n'

print(html_card)
```

It was a lot easier to see what was going in the code by simplifying the HTML. One way to do that would be to make a string outside the the loop that you can use as a template with the call to format.

Comment: I cant thank you enough, that is absolutely what I was looking for.